# Where is the color code for darkbrown defined? (RGB value)

Tags: color, default

Where can I find the color code for `darkbrown`, so it's corresponding RGB value? It is not defined in `xcolors`.

Comment: `xcolor` does not define a color named `darkbrown` but you can define your own using the `\newcolor` command or take the `brown` from `xcolor` and mix it with black as in `brown!50!black`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `texdoc xcolors`, I did a search for `darkbrown`.

On page 10 is `\definecolor{darkbrown}{rgb}{0.4, 0.26, 0.13}`

Comment: Apparently, `texdoc xcolors` brought up the `latexcolors` package.

Comment: Can you link an online reference? I could not find it in mine. Maybe my version is too old.

Comment: Ok, I could find it in the `latexcolors` package, on page 10, as you mentioned it: http://mirror.kumi.systems/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/latexcolors/latexcolors.pdf